# How to read data from external list using Workflow in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I want to access the External list and update the my list fields from this External list using workflow.In my External list contains Customer Name, City, Address i want to update this value to my list.

Comment: And your problem using SharePoint Designer is?

Comment: Yes i am  using SharePoint Designer 2013 i want to create using workflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Workflow doesn’t support external list in SharePoint 2013 ,

- You cannot actually run a workflow on an external list.
- You neither have the option to define any workflows nor can you actually start one. `External List = No Workflows in SharePoint 2013!`

**Workaround**  :  Try SharePoint 2010 workflow by using Start a list/site workflow action inside the SharePoint 2013 workflow.

For more details check

- [SharePoint Server 2013 known issues](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Server-2013-known-issues-780242a6-236e-4d7a-8379-118a1aaa2a51?CorrelationId=fd9cf927-1a2c-493c-9556-6f470806f92c&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#_SharePoint_Designer)
- [External List Limitations in SharePoint 2010/2013](https://blog.devoworx.net/2013/01/01/external-list-limitations-in-sharepoint/)